# Xamarin Android mvvmlight setCommand Invalid cast

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I am using Xamarin Android with mvvmlight 5.0 library. I was happy that I can use the data binding in my app. It was working well in some simple event like "Click". However, I got something strange when I bind to a event, which is the NavigationClick event of Support Toolbar. I got an invalid cast error as following:

```
10-23 04:35:05.790 I/MonoDroid(11948): System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
10-23 04:35:05.790 I/MonoDroid(11948): at (wrapper castclass) object.__castclass_with_cache (object,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0002c, 0x0006f>
10-23 04:35:05.790 I/MonoDroid(11948): at System.Reflection.EventInfo.AddEventFrame<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar, System.EventHandler`1<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar/NavigationClickEventArgs>> (System.Reflection.EventInfo/AddEvent`2<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar, System.EventHandler`1<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar/NavigationClickEventArgs>>,object,object) <0x00123>
10-23 04:35:05.790 I/MonoDroid(11948): at System.Reflection.EventInfo.AddEventHandler (object,System.Delegate) [0x00074] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/EventInfo.cs:110
10-23 04:35:05.790 I/MonoDroid(11948): at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Helpers.Extensions.SetCommand<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar/NavigationClickEventArgs> (object,string,GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand`1<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar/NavigationClickEventArgs>,GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Helpers.Binding) <0x002b4>
10-23 04:35:05.790 I/MonoDroid(11948): at LieferwagenAndroid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00051] in C:\Users\echan1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\LieferwagenAndroid\LieferwagenAndroid\MainActivity.cs:51
10-23 04:35:05.790 I/MonoDroid(11948): at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00013, 0x0008e>
10-23 04:35:05.790 I/MonoDroid(11948): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.c16833d5-e3e1-469e-9a3a-e4abfcb667ff (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00027>
10-23 04:35:05.794 W/art     (11948): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable
10-23 04:35:05.796 D/AndroidRuntime(11948): Shutting down VM
```

In the Activity, I used the setCommand:

```
_supporttoolbar.SetCommand("NavigationClick", App.Locator.Main.NavigationCommand);
```

In my ViewModel class, I declare the RealyCommand as the following:

```
NavigationCommand = new RelayCommand(NavigationClickMethod);

    public void NavigationClickMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Navigation Clicked......");
    }
```

Therefore, if there is the some parameters missing, how can I know what kinds of parameters should be passed? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure about the event name ? Isn't "Click" instead of "NavigationClick" ?

EDIT : You should try this event "OnOptionsItemSelected"

Answer (score -1):

This is a but I ran into with Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin.Android.  Its a but on Xamarin's part.  You'll need to open up your projects .csproj file then add the missing items.  As an Example :

```
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="System.Runtime" />
<Reference Include="System.Globalization" />
<Reference Include="System.ObjectModel" />
<Reference Include="System.Net.Primitives" />
```

These where the references I was missing in mine.